# ReactJS Link tag - Uncaught ReferenceError: Link is not defined

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

How do I add `<a>` tag correctly? I get this error for adding `<Link></Link>`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Link is not defined
```

The code:

```
   render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link className="button-close-overlay"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></Link>
                <article>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="content align-center" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.article.content}}></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

The entire code:

```
class Article extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            article: [],
        };
    }

    // Then fetch the data using $.get():
    componentDidMount() {
        this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
            this.setState({
                article: result
            });
        }.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <link className="button-close-overlay"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></link>
                <article>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="content align-center" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.article.content}}></div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export { Article as default }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're thinking of the React router `Link`. Then you need to import it.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
```

or

```
var Link = require('react-router').Link
```

otherwise rendering a pure `<a>` does the trick!

Comment: Aww I see! will fallback to `<a>` which is better!  thanks! :-)

Comment: @HenrikAndersson This import from react-router does not work in react-router 4+, you must import from react-router-dom instead

Answer (score 18):

another option would be

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Nextjs, you can also use Link from next/link

```
import Link from "next/link"
```

Comment: This just work. https://github.com/zeit/next-learn-demo/blob/master/2-using-shared-components/pages/index.js